# How insert into a new table from another table cross joined with another table

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using Python and SQLite to manipulate a database.

I have a SQLite table `Movies` in database `Data` that looks like this:

```
| ID             | Country     
+----------------+-------------
| 1              | USA, Germany, Mexico 
| 2              | Brazil, Peru
| 3              | Peru
```

I have a table `Countries` in the same database that looks like this

```
| ID             | Country     
+----------------+-------------
| 1              | USA
| 1              | Germany
| 1              | Mexico
| 2              | Brazil
| 2              | Peru
| 3              | Peru
```

I want to insert from database `Data` all movies from Peru into a new database `PeruData` that looks like this

```
| ID             | Country     
+----------------+-------------
| 2              | Peru
| 3              | Peru
```

I'm new to SQL and having trouble programming the right query.

Here's my attempt:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("PeruData.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Movies (ID, Country);")
cur.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'Data.db' AS other;")
cur.execute("\
        INSERT INTO Movies \
        (ID, Country) \
        SELECT ID, Country
        FROM other.Movies CROSS JOIN other.Countries\
        WHERE other.Movies.ID = other.Countries.ID AND other.Countries.Country = 'Peru'\

con.commit()
con.close()
```

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong because I get the error

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: other.Countries

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Did you try to execute the query alone (`SELECT ID, Country ...`) directly in sqlite3?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround which successfully got the result you wanted.

---

Instead of having to write `con = sqlite3.connect("data.db")` and then having to write `con.commit()` and `con.close()`, you can shorten your code to written like this:

```
with sqlite3.connect("Data.db") as connection:
    c = connection.cursor()
```

This way you won't have to commit the changes and close each time you're working with a database. Just a nifty shortcut I learned. Now onto your code...

Personally, I'm unfamiliar with the SQL statement **ATTACH DATABASE**. I would incorporate your new database at the *end* of your program instead that way you can avoid any conflicts that you aren't knowledgeable of handling (such as your OperationalError given). So first I would begin to get the desired result *and then* insert that into your new table. Your third execution statement can be rewritten like so:

```
c.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT Movies.ID, Countries.Country
        FROM Movies
        CROSS JOIN Countries
        WHERE Movies.ID = Countries.ID AND Countries.Country = 'Peru'
        """)
```

This does the job, but you need to use **fetchall()** to return your result set in a list of tuples which can then be inserted into your new table. So you'd type this:

```
rows = c.fetchall()
```

Now you can open a new connection by creating the "PeruData.db" database, creating the table, and inserting the values.

```
with sqlite3.connect("PeruData.db") as connection:
    c = connection.cursor()

    c.execute("CREATE TABLE Movies (ID INT, Country TEXT)")
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO Movies VALUES(?, ?)", rows)
```

That's it.
Hope I was able to answer your question!

Comment: Great to know! Thanks.

Comment: Yep, no problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

The current error is probably caused by a typo or other minor problem. I could create the databases described here and successfully do the insert after fixing minor errors: a missing backslash at an end of line and adding qualifiers for the selected columns.

But I also advise your to use aliases for the tables in multi-table selects. The code that works in my test is:

```
cur.execute("\
        INSERT INTO Movies \
        (ID, Country) \
        SELECT m.ID, c.Country\
        FROM other.Movies  m CROSS JOIN other.Countries c \
        WHERE m.ID = c.ID AND c.Country = 'Peru'")
```